# Loading truffle library in remix browser IDE

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

Besides writing smart contracts in the browser, I would also like to write my test in this IDE. Any suggestions how to load the truffle files in http://remix.ethereum.org?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remix has a test capability absolutely similar integrated. Watch at “test” tab and read the example that come in the “browser” dir every time you load the IDE.

If you are in comfort using truffle test, you shall be very quickly ready to use Remix capability.

Hoping this helps.